# Technical term for getting stuck at local optimum when building a mechanistic model

Tags: modeling, model

I'm looking for a technical term or literature that describes a problem when creating mechanistic computer models.

By mechanistic computer model, I mean a computer model of a physical system where the different components of the physical system are modelled by components of the computer model, each model component represents a different mechanism in the system.

The error in a mechanistic model will be caused by different mechanisms being poorly represented or missing entirely.

The term I'm looking for is to describe the following situation (or literature that addresses this problem):

You improve one of the components of the model, say by adding detail that you know better represents the underlying physical process. However, the model performance as a whole gets worse, because the error in the component you improved was cancelling out the error in another component of the model.

Comment: I would describe this as "the model is losing consistency" because the level of description of some parts of it does not match (i.e., is not consistent with) the description used for some other parts.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: *Welcome to SciComp!* You've chosen a challenging question as your first question. It may take you a few iterations to express it clearly enough for an answer, so keep an eye on the comments and try to address them as they occur, preferably by *editing/improving your question* and not just answering in a comment. I usually write the titles to my question last rather than first, because I discover that by the time I get to the end of writing the post I understand more about what I need to know than when I begin.

Comment: I don't think you really want to ask for a "technical term for getting stuck at local optimum" as much as you want a term for the performance (defined how?) getting worse for what *you feel is* a more physically justifiable model. There might not be a specific technical term for that as such, but certainly there are some sets of parameters that due to [strong correlations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation) between parameters. To check for that one can do a parameter correlation analysis for your model.

Comment: One can also check out [Statistics SE and search for "correlation analysis"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=correlation+analysis) and discover potentially hundreds of posts that might also be helpful. There are [almost 200 different SE sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday)!